14GB 100% free Healthy (Primary Parition) after Windows 7 install
I recently bought a new SSD to put in a really old laptop and installed Windows 7 on it. It's just for some very old software and hardware that I still want to use that are not supported in Windows 10 and up.
Just now I took a look at Disk Management and saw there's an almost 15GB partition that is empty. I know about recovery partitions, but those are usually called Recovery Partition and have some file system. This one is just Primary Partition and no file system. When I right click on it, the only option is "delete". Also usually they would be to the right of the C partition, and this is to the left.
Could it still be a recovery partition? Would it be so big?
What else could it be? Could I just delete it? It's quite a lot of space to be sitting there empty. Especially that I want to dual boot Linux on there.


“Could it still be a recovery partition?” - No; it contains no data.

@Ramhound I've seen many posts of people saying that their recovery partition is showing as 100% free, even if it is in fact the recovery partition.

Recovery partition isn’t supposed to be the first partition, it’s also optional, and can be recreated if by some oddity the partition actually is your recovery partition. A recovery partition that is useable is never 100% free. Your system partition is also your boot partition which will prevent you from dual booting.

@Ramhound You mean I won't be able to install Linux as dual boot? There's no way I'll be able to? What would happen if I tried to install Linux?

In order to dual boot your boot partition cannot be the same partition as Windows. You can reinstall Windows 7 in a standard configuration and then dual boot but you will run into issues trying to dual boot with the partition schema you have today. Which is why a VM is probably the way to go

@Ramhound... damn, that sucks then. I thought I did standard configuration when I installed it. I mean, I just used the Windows 7 recovery disks and installed normally. There wasn't even any option to install it any other way.
My laptop has two HDD slots. What if I buy another SSD for the second slot to install Linux there? Or would that count as dual boot also as far as Windows is concerned?

@Ramhound I posted on sevenforums and someone is saying that it's actually better if system and boot are on the same partition for dual booting. They gave a good explanation as to why also. If you care to check it, you can see it here: https://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/429255-14gb-100-free-healthy-primary-parition-after-windows-7-install.html#post3528916

I don’t see where that was actually said, but I saw a comment saying WinRE should be 100% free and be functional, and that’s completely wrong.

Strange, don't know where you saw that about WinRE. I don't see it anywhere. And I linked directly to the post talking about dual booting. It's the last 2 paragraphs on that post. Starting with "As for dual-booting linux...."

You will have to quote the relevant conversation.  I don't even need to read the conversation from that link, the statement that the WinRE partition can be 100% free, is absolutely incorrect.

It's too long too quote. I don't know where you're seeing that statement. Does it say specifically WinRE? I did write that I have a 100% free partition in there, but not WinRE. You might have ended up at a wrong thread somehow.

Even if there is that exact statement in there somewhere, it could have been from a different person. Many people commented on the thread. If one person says something wrong, doesn't mean every single person commenting on the thread will also be wrong.
